# Public encryption scheme where decryption key become valid on certain timestamp?

Tags: asymmetric

I am looking for a solution in asymmetric cryptography where the decryption will only be possible after a certain condition i.e. after certain time passed or on certain date. The key and cipher should be submitted at once. There is no central authority to keep the checks. Is there any procedure?

**A Rough Idea:**`Can we add some nonce as a puzzle in key so that the procedure of finding the exact key take some guaranteed time?`

Or any known method?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606) on crypto.se

Comment: What you are referring to is known as a time-lock puzzle - question has been asked here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/606/time-capsule-cryptography

Specifically read PulpSpy's answer as he explains it quite well.